# This encoded code is the code that encoded the code

Tags: cipher, symbols

This gibberish is the source code of what you use to encode and decode it. I'm curious if anybody can decode it and give me the original source code! I'm placing a decent bounty on this *in two days* because I think it's quite funny.

https://hastebin.com/aqezusomut.js

The text consists of the following characters: **< > + - =**

Comment: ^vote with question/note: Was the text too big to include in this post? Sure would've been nice, perhaps with a shorter cipher.  I tend to ignore posts that require link chasing but reluctantly wound up liking this puzzle after seeing its solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Steps - First:

> Show text [like this](https://hastebin.com/raw/aqezusomut)

Second:

> Search in text (ctrl+F) for "<>" or "<=-<>=+<" You will notice, that it is repetitive.
>  [image: chaos]

Third:

> Ignore "<" and "<=-<>=+<", translate "+" and "-" as "1" and "0".
>  ">" is separator.

Fourth:

> You can now see binary code, it needs to be slightly changed from this
>  [image: binary]
>  To this, when you add "0" at the start of each string (so it has 8 symbols each). Maybe I missed something, because I had to do it by hand.
>  [image: better binary]

Fifth:

> Translate binary to text ([for example here](https://www.boxentriq.com/code-breaking/numbers-to-letters)) and it gives text [like this](https://hastebin.com/ixolopemin.cpp)
>  [image: source code]
>  Which is (I believe) same algorithm, that was used on its source code.

Comment: Very close!! Nice job